# Swift Error: exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I've looked on the site for the answer to my problem, but I could not find a solution that would work for me. I am getting the error code every time I run my application on the Iphone 5 simulator. But I do not get the error on Iphone 6 and up. Why is this? It will crash when I press a button or it will crash as soon as I go to the third screen.

```
func pickQuestion () {

    if (Questions.count  > 0 ) && (numberWrong < 4 ){
    ***qNum = Int(arc4random()) % Questions.count***
    qLabel.text = Questions[qNum].Question
    answerNum = Questions[qNum].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count {

            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[qNum].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: qNum)

}
    else {

        actioncall()

    }
func actioncall () {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc: GameOverViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Game Over") as! GameOverViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353309/swift-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop).